# ValueError: ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['class_mode'])

Tags: keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation  
from keras.optimizers import SGD  
from keras.datasets import mnist  
import numpy 

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(500,input_shape=(784,))) # 28*28=784  
model.add(Activation('tanh')) # tanh  
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 50% dropout

model.add(Dense(500)) # 500个
model.add(Activation('tanh'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax')) 


sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, class_mode='categorical') 

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]) 
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1] * X_test.shape[2])  
Y_train = (numpy.arange(10) == y_train[:, None]).astype(int) 
Y_test = (numpy.arange(10) == y_test[:, None]).astype(int)

model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=200,epochs=50,shuffle=True,verbose=0,validation_split=0.3)
model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=200, verbose=0)

print("test set")
scores = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test,batch_size=200,verbose=0)
print("")
print("The test loss is %f" % scores)
result = model.predict(X_test,batch_size=200,verbose=0)
```

I found this post Error when profiling keras models, which modifies the tensorflow library.

So, I checked Keras library code from the link. But could not find anything like ['class_mode'] to modify the keras library. Next, I tried running the code after re-installing keras, but even that didn't work.

I used anaconda to import Kreas， maybe I install wrong?

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: class_mode is not a parameter for model.compile, what exactly are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

remove class_mode='categorical',it runs